# Error on live server when requesting Docusign JWT user token for remote signing

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk, docusignapextoolkit

I integrated docusign remote signing in my laravel project. It was working fine but unfortunately from previous two days , same code throws error on live server when I tried to request JWT user token.

The error is..

```
API call to https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token failed, but for an unknown reason. This could happen if you are disconnected from the network.
```

This is the code from where error arises..

```
private function getToken(ApiClient $apiClient): string
    {
        try {
            $privateKey = \File::get(storage_path(env('DS_KEY_PATH')));
            $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                $ikey = env('DS_CLIENT_ID'),
                $userId = env('DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_ID'),
                $key = $privateKey,
                $scope = env('DS_JWT_SCOPE')
            );
            $token = $response[0];
            $accessToken = $token->getAccessToken();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            dd($th->getMessage());
            throw $th;
        }
        return $accessToken;
    }
```

The main point from where error arises is this piece of code..

```
$response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                $ikey = env('DS_CLIENT_ID'),
                $userId = env('DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_ID'),
                $key = $privateKey,
                $scope = env('DS_JWT_SCOPE')
            );
```

Comment: Are you running this from a server? cloud? your laptop? this looks like a networking issue, related to proxy/VPN/Firewall/Antivirus etc. Can you try to isolate the situation? where does it work? where does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using the production OAuth service provider, https://account.docusign.com

Best is to record a log of your app's network events and check the log.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74396257/64904)